# What happens to a solute's potential energy during diffusion?

Tags: aqueous-solution, diffusion, osmosis

I was thinking, if you have a large amount of water, with an uneven solute concentration, diffusion will lead to an even concentration of solute throughout the solution.

Intuitively,that would mean that our system initially has a large amount of potential energy, and that it decreases to a minimum.

[image: Text]

I feel like this raises two questions :

Firstly, from which force does this inital "osmotic" potential energy derive ?

Secondly, under what form is this potential energy realeased once concentration equilibrium is reached ?

What's more, if you consider a cell membrane with a great concentration difference between one side, and another, simple diffusion will lead solute molecules to pass through the membrane. So, in order to pass through the membrane, a solute would have to expend potential energy : the diffusion reaction would have a certain activation energy.
Under what form is this energy then dissipated ? It would first become kinetic enrgy, allowing the solute to pass through the membrane, but what form would it then take ? Simply heat energy ?

Any answer would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It seems to be a problem of entropy, and not a problem of internal energy.

Comment: Both entropy and enthalpy of mixing are important and looks like OP hadn't looked up neither.

Answer (score 1):

Energy *can* be recovered across a concentration gradient, as in [osmotic power production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmotic_power).

But you ask, if I understand correctly what happens if the energy is *not* harvested? The same thing that would happen if you dropped a weight:

- If the weight is attached so as to spin a generator, then the potential energy can be converted to electric energy.
- If the weight is allowed to impact a surface, instead, then the potential energy is converted to heat.

If economics is considered the [dismal science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_dismal_science), thermodynamics is equally grim. Consider [Ginsberg's Theorem](https://www.barrypopik.com/index.php/new_york_city/entry/you_cant_win_you_cant_break_even)

1. You can’t win.
2. You can’t break even.
3. You can’t get out of the game.